# Get line of file content that contain a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, fs

I wanted to get line content in a file that contains a string in discord js node.

Something like this:

```js
If (file contains("string")){
console.log(line content)
}
```

like, if one of the lines in the file contains the string. It's gonna send the line that contains the string to the console.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show the code you tried and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: So basically I want to find the latest file in the folder, so I decided to list all the file names in a text file and since the file names contain dates in the middle I can find the latest file by finding the line that contains the date.

Comment: Cool, so show us the code you tried, explain what you want it to do and what it actually does or where the problem is and we can help you fix it. Don't expect anyone to write the code for you, that's not what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: Well so far I have tried:

const testFolder = './logs/Chatlogs';
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});

var date = "2021"+"12"+"03"
if(file.includes(date)){
get line content?
}

Comment: Add it to your question so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

So all you need is to split the file content by new line and iterate over the lines to find the date like so:

```
const testFolder = './logs/Chatlogs';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);

    // read the file content
    var content = fs.readFileSync(path.join(testFolder, file));

    var date = '20211203';
    var lines = content.split('\n');

    lines.forEach(l => {
        if(l.indexOf(date) > -1)
            console.log('Found it:', l);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tested it out and it didn't work, I got Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'abyssal luckers_20210911_151259_2118715187.txt'

Comment: @somekidplayingjs I fixed the code by changing `fs.readFileSync(file);` to `fs.readFileSync(path.join(testFolder, file));` but this is really simple stuff you should be able to figure this out by yourself.

Comment: nah, I just started learning discord.js its pretty hard for me. Cuz I'm a kid